# Gem for enumerating an IP range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for a Gem that can take in start IP and an end IP address and give me the IPs in the middle.

I've seen 'ipaddress-gem' but this takes an IP and a netmask when you want a range, I want something that gives me IPs between 2 arbitrary IPs.
For example give me all the IPs between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.23 for example.

Does anything like this actually exist?

Comment: You don't need a Gem. `Range` has a `to_a` method, that will return an `Array`.